# Difference between sectors used for Flash and IAP?

Tags: c, embedded, flash

Here is a picture of sectors on on-chip 512kb Flash memory on LPC 1788, and the question is what's the difference between sectors 0 to 19 and 20 to 29. Can 0 to 19 be used in IAP or not and vice-versa?

[image]

Comment: A datasheet link would be helpful.

Comment: http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10470.pdf Here it is.

Comment: Where is that info? Linked datasheet is Rev 3.1 15 September 2014, and I don't see info from your question.

Comment: @Lazar Can't find anything saying like that!